# Ошибка Fatal error: Class 'Instaphp' not found

Tags: php, классы, instagram-api

Помогите исправить проблему! почему то код не видит класс. вот собственно и сам код:

```
<?php
session_start();
$access_token = null;
/* check to see if we have an access token stored in the session */
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['access_token']))
    $access_token = $_SESSION["access_token"];

/*
 Get our Instaphp instance passing the $access_token
 Once the access_token is set, there's no need to pass
 it along in subsequent api calls as it is automatically
 passed.
*/
$api = Instaphp::Instance($access_token);

/* if the access_token is empty, do your authentication here */
if (empty($access_token)) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
        $res = $api->Users->Authenticate($_REQUEST["code"]);
        if (empty($res->error) $$ !empty($res->auth->access_token)) {
            $_SESSION["access_token"] = $res->auth->access_token;
            /* store the user object in the session as well... don't forget to serialize */
            $_SESSION["auth_user"] = @serialize($res->auth->user);
        }
    }
}

/* 
 no need to create any new Instaphp objects. 
 They're already setup in the main Instaphp object.
*/
$recent = $api->Users->Recent("self");

/* Your data should be here */
print_r($recent->data);
?>
```

К нему подключается класс Instaphp. Вот код файла Instaphp.php:

```
<?php
namespace Instaphp {

    use \SimpleXMLElement;

    /**
     * The Instaphp version. We pass this to Instagram as part of the User-Agent
     */
    define('INSTAPHP_VERSION', '1.0');

    /**
     * Our Config class which extends the SimpleXMLElement class
     * See {inline @link http://php.net/simplexmlelement SimplXMLElement}
     * @package Instaphp
     * @version 1.0
     * @author randy sesser <randy@instaphp.com>
     */
    class Config extends SimpleXMLElement
    {

        /**
         * A static instance property for creating an instance of the Config object
         * @var Instaphp\Config
         * @access private
         */
        private static $_instance = null;
        /**
         * The path to the config.xml file
         * @var string
         * @access private
         */
        private static $file = null;

        /**
         * Singleton method since the SimpleXMLElement class is essentially "sealed"
         * @return Config An instance of the Config object
         */
        public static function Instance()
        {
            if (static::$file == null)
                static::$file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.xml';

            if (!file_exists(static::$file)) {
                trigger_error("No configuration found for Instaphp. Using sample file!", E_USER_WARNING);
                static::$file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.sample.xml';
            }

            if (null == static::$_instance)
                static::$_instance = new self(static::$file, null, true);

            return static::$_instance;
        }

        /**
         * A convenience method to build the OAuth URL to authenticate a user.
         * the value in the config.xml file should contain some "tokens" that
         * are replaced with other values in the config.
         * @access public
         * @return string The OAuth URL used to authenticate a user
         */
        public function GetOAuthUri()
        {
            if (!isset($this->Instagram))
                return null;

            $path = $this->Instagram->OAuthPath;
            $path = str_replace("{ClientId}", $this->Instagram->ClientId, $path);
            $path = str_replace("{RedirectUri}", $this->Instaphp->RedirectUri, $path);

            if (!empty($this->Instagram->Scope))
                $path .= '&scope=' . $this->Instagram->Scope;

            return $this->Instagram->Endpoint . $path;
        }

        /**
         * A convenience method to build the OAuth URL used to retreive an access token
         * @return string The URL used to retrieve the access token
         */
        public function GetOAuthTokenUri()
        {
            if (!isset($this->Instagram))
                return null;

            return $this->Instagram->Endpoint . $this->Instagram->OAuthTokenPath;
        }

        public function CacheSetting($name, $key)
        {
            $cache = $this->xpath("//Instaphp/Cache[@Engine='File']");
            if (empty($cache) || count($cache) == 0)
                return null;

            $cache = $cache[0];

            return $cache->Settings->Setting[$key];

        }

        public function GetSection($section = null, \SimpleXMLElement $parent = null)
        {
            if (empty($section))
                return null;

            if (null !== $parent)
                return $parent->xpath($section);

            return $this->xpath($section);
        }

    }

}
```

Помогите... Исходники брал на гитхабе...
https://github.com/sesser/Instaphp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во первых Instaphp это не класс  а пространстов имен)
версия php какая?

где подключение файла Instaphp ?

если версия выше 5.3. то  по видимому у вас вместо

```
$api = Instaphp::Instance($access_token);
```

нада вот так

```
$api = Instaphp\Config::Instance($access_token);
```

так как Instance это статистический метод класса Config, а не функция опеределенная в пространстве Instaphp

Пока не покажите как заюзали подключение файла Instaphp ответа точного не будет...